# Why can't I test for errors in redux-toolkit reducer with jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

```
const cartsSlice = createSlice({
  name: CARTS,
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increaseCartItemQuantityById: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<{ cartItemId: number }>) => {
      const targetIndex = state.carts.value.findIndex(
        (cartItem) => cartItem.id === payload.cartItemId,
      );

      if (targetIndex === -1) throw new Error('mismatched id');

      state.carts.value[targetIndex].quantity = state.carts.value[targetIndex].quantity + 1;
    },
```

I want to test whether a reducer throws an error well. So I try to test using thThrow, thThrowError etc..

I tried it

```
it('throw error test', () => {
      const MISMATCHED_ID = 1;

      const error = new Error('mismatched id');

      expect(
        cartsReducer(
          cartsReducerInitialState,
          increaseCartItemQuantityById({ cartItemId: MISMATCHED_ID }),
        ),
      )
    .toThrowError(error); // fail
    .toThrow(error); // fail
    .toThrowErrror('mismatched id'); // fail
    .toThrowErrror(/mismatched id/); // fail
    .toHaveErrorMessage(/mismatched id/); // fail
    .toHaveErrorMessage('mismatched id'); // fail
    });
  });
```

All these ways are failed... It only returned this message

FAIL  store/modules/carts/**tests**/cartsReducer.test.ts
●  › increaseCartItemQuantityById › throw error test

```
mismatched id

  37 |     },
  38 |   } as CartsReducerState,
> 39 |   reducers: {
     |                        ^
  40 |     addCartItem: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<{ newCartItem: CartItem }>) => {
  41 |       state.carts.value = [...state.carts.value, payload.newCartItem];
  42 |     },

  at increaseCartItemQuantityById (store/modules/carts/slice.ts:39:43)
  at recipe (node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/createReducer.ts:280:20)
  at Immer.produce (node_modules/immer/src/core/immerClass.ts:94:14)
  at node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/createReducer.ts:279:18
      at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
  at reducer (node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/createReducer.ts:246:25)
  at Object.reducer [as cartsReducer] (node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/createSlice.ts:325:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (store/modules/carts/__tests__/cartsReducer.test.ts:55:32)
```

Comment: Where does the `cartsReducer` come from in your test file? Show the code

Comment: I thought that expressions that throw should be wrapped in a function... i.e. `expect(() => exprThatThrows()).toThrow(...)`